# jquery arguments.callee

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to adjust a jquery script to my needs and encountered the following lines-

```
 arguments.callee.eabad1be5eed94cb0232f71c2e5ce5 = function() {
            _c3();
            _c4();
            return;
        };
```

what is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arguments is an object that holds callee that holds the variable eabad1be5eed94cb0232f71c2e5ce5 which is being turned into a function or method by the 
function() {
            _c3();
            _c4();
            return;
        };

from what I see...

Comment: but `arguments` is not just *any object*

Answer (score 7):

`arguments.callee` refers to the function begin called. So your code assign a function to the `eabad1be5eed94cb0232f71c2e5ce5` property of the function you're in.

To demonstrate this. Here's a snippet of code in which a function `g()` is assigned to a property of another function `f()` using `argument.callee`:

```
function f() {
    arguments.callee.g = function() {alert("Hello, World!")};
}

f();
f.g();  // Alerts "Hello, World!"
```

I'm not exactly sure what the code you posted is suppose to do.

`argument.callee` is often used inside anonymous functions to refer to themselves. Though I believe it can't be used in ECMAScript 5 *strict mode*.